# React native IOS touch event need to tap twice when the keypad is opened

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, reactjs, react-native

I am using sub component which having textInput fields inside the Flatlist. when i click on the submit button first time just keypad dismissed and my second attempt catch the actual submit event.

```
    <FlatList
    ref={(ref) => { this.flatListRef = ref; }}
    data={this.state.pannelData}                   
    keyExtractor={item => item.type}
    getItemLayout={this.getItemLayout}                    
    keyboardShouldPersistTaps='handled'
    scrollEventThrottle={16}
    ListFooterComponent={() => { return <FooterComponent/> }} />
```

Issue is only on IOS and android working as expected.
react - "^16.3.1"
react-native - "^0.55.3"

Answer (score 0):

Use this prop `keyboardShouldPersistTaps={true}` with your Flatlist.

Comment: i also try keyboardShouldPersistTaps='always' which is mentioned on the documentation but issue is still there